# Issue with ggmap geom_point

Tags: r, ggmap

I'm working on a Shiny app, but my issue is with the production of a map.

I read the data in with

```
tabaco <-read.csv("TabacoUse.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Using the widget selections, I filter it.  So for example, if the user has chosen the state of Alabama and the class of smoker "Current Smoker", then the data will filter down to this

```
structure(list(Year = c(2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
2007L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 
2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 
2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 
2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2004L, 
2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 
2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2003L, 2003L, 
2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 
2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 
2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 
2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 
2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 
2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2000L, 2000L, 1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 
1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 
1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 
1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 1997L, 
1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 
1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 
1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 
1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L), State = c("Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama"
), Gender = c("Female", "Female", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Male", "Overall", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Female", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Female", "Overall", "Overall", "Male", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Female", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Female", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", 
"Male", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Female", "Overall", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Female", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Male", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Female", "Overall", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Male", "Overall", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Female", "Overall", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Male", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Female", "Female", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Male", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Female", "Overall", "Female", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Female", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Female", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Male", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Female", 
"Overall", "Female", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Male", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Female", 
"Overall", "Male", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", 
"Female", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Male", "Female", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Female", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Female", "Male", "Overall", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Female", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Female", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Female", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", 
"Male", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Male", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Female", "Female", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Female", "Overall", "Male", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Overall", "Female", "Overall", "Overall", 
"Overall", "Overall", "Overall"), Type.of.Smoker = c("Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", "Current Smoking", 
"Current Smoking"), Data_Value = c(18.7, 18.6, 21.5, 21.8, 10.3, 
21.9, 22.8, 24.3, 25.5, 25.8, 26.4, 27.9, 36.7, 38.1, 38.2, 16.5, 
16.4, 16.7, 10.5, 17.6, 18, 19.7, 20.6, 22.5, 22.6, 23.1, 24.4, 
25, 25.7, 26.5, 26.6, 26.9, 33.7, 36.5, 40.6, 7.8, 14.8, 16.9, 
17, 19.3, 21, 22.1, 22.3, 22.6, 23, 23.3, 24.7, 25.2, 26.1, 29.1, 
35.3, 38.1, 16.5, 34.3, 17.1, 17.4, 19.6, 21.2, 22.5, 22.8, 23.2, 
24, 24.7, 25.1, 25.7, 27.3, 28.9, 29, 32.8, 8.9, 9.7, 19.2, 17.6, 
19.8, 23.4, 24.7, 24.9, 25, 25.2, 25.9, 26.1, 27.2, 33.2, 37.9, 
34.9, 23.2, 20.5, 26.2, 9.6, 37.4, 35.7, 31.9, 31.5, 29.6, 28.1, 
27.4, 26.6, 26, 24.8, 24.4, 20.4, 19.9, 18.8, 18.7, 22.5, 34.6, 
38.5, 29.1, 28.9, 28.1, 26.9, 26.7, 26.3, 25.5, 24.9, 23.8, 21.9, 
21.2, 19.5, 19.4, 12.1, 29.4, 21.4, 11.4, 21.2, 21.4, 22.5, 24.3, 
25.3, 25.4, 25.6, 26.9, 27.3, 28, 28.4, 28.5, 33.3, 36.1, 31.7, 
12, 17.9, 18.9, 21.5, 21.5, 23.7, 24, 24.3, 24.4, 25.5, 26.2, 
27.5, 27.5, 31.6, 32.3, 35.5, 9, 31.9, 31.8, 29.7, 28.8, 27.9, 
27.7, 25.8, 25.1, 24.6, 23.8, 23.2, 22.1, 19.7, 18.7, 18.5, 31, 
33.9, 33.4, 32.3, 30.5, 28.9, 27.1, 25.5, 25.2, 24.8, 24.5, 24, 
22, 22, 20.2, 19.3, 11.1, 24.7, 33.9, 31.6, 29.2, 28.5, 27.2, 
26.2, 25.4, 24.6, 23.5, 21.6, 21.1, 18, 16.9, 16.8, 11.9, 24.9, 
12.8, 14.9, 18.3, 19.1, 20.3, 22.3, 24.6, 24.7, 25.5, 26.2, 27.2, 
27.9, 28, 29.5, 31.6, 33.2, 24.6, 36.1, 35.7, 30.9, 28.6, 27.2, 
26.1, 25.8, 25.3, 24.7, 21.2, 20.4, 20, 19.9, 16.4, 13.9, 24.5, 
30.3, 29.2, 29, 25.7, 24.9, 24.7, 24.3, 22.9, 22.4, 21.8, 20.7, 
20.2, 18.2, 17.5, 12.7, 24.5), Sample_Size = c(5234L, 1197L, 
5349L, 104L, 2733L, 7624L, 1856L, 3097L, 2390L, 2528L, 2475L, 
1521L, 1143L, 1165L, 62L, 3792L, 211L, 3718L, 2196L, 3305L, 3390L, 
4661L, 1801L, 6756L, 4638L, 1163L, 2791L, 218L, 2095L, 2279L, 
2231L, 1491L, 925L, 951L, 105L, 1959L, 72L, 3339L, 3264L, 4387L, 
1732L, 6471L, 1185L, 2001L, 4432L, 1528L, 2052L, 2084L, 2740L, 
204L, 953L, 972L, 108L, 1180L, 3515L, 3426L, 4895L, 1966L, 7219L, 
4879L, 1410L, 2312L, 3024L, 1802L, 2324L, 2382L, 70L, 257L, 1154L, 
2081L, 853L, 1638L, 676L, 1678L, 668L, 1039L, 2425L, 108L, 1004L, 
1380L, 1126L, 912L, 498L, 508L, 59L, 3278L, 2152L, 2325L, 802L, 
495L, 483L, 79L, 148L, 1062L, 953L, 1017L, 1264L, 979L, 3192L, 
740L, 2130L, 1620L, 682L, 1553L, 869L, 542L, 563L, 228L, 1226L, 
1153L, 1195L, 1141L, 1348L, 2507L, 3587L, 905L, 87L, 2361L, 1758L, 
1655L, 844L, 231L, 56L, 742L, 1624L, 1728L, 2151L, 733L, 3336L, 
2395L, 824L, 989L, 1041L, 1242L, 1093L, 1185L, 459L, 483L, 85L, 
687L, 1403L, 1504L, 2052L, 654L, 847L, 2226L, 1095L, 3088L, 962L, 
1072L, 1036L, 1021L, 488L, 497L, 219L, 542L, 52L, 456L, 433L, 
927L, 791L, 859L, 1048L, 253L, 1997L, 2789L, 922L, 1741L, 602L, 
1215L, 1322L, 1048L, 378L, 363L, 200L, 839L, 836L, 645L, 1634L, 
2234L, 680L, 731L, 750L, 1060L, 1398L, 974L, 498L, 431L, 603L, 
421L, 403L, 209L, 753L, 547L, 852L, 1546L, 658L, 2088L, 685L, 
1236L, 961L, 860L, 456L, 429L, 650L, 498L, 75L, 996L, 910L, 508L, 
1460L, 2244L, 199L, 710L, 1597L, 784L, 750L, 704L, 829L, 419L, 
435L, 2169L, 417L, 406L, 826L, 810L, 1626L, 694L, 659L, 672L, 
641L, 1359L, 865L, 213L, 978L, 442L, 444L, 595L, 50L, 401L, 390L, 
933L, 719L, 660L, 781L, 1599L, 2137L, 202L, 1356L, 453L, 922L, 
1023L, 400L, 612L), Lat = c(32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 32.84057112, 
32.84057112), Lon = c(-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, -86.63186076, 
-86.63186076)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -254L
), .Names = c("Year", "State", "Gender", "Type.of.Smoker", "Data_Value", 
"Sample_Size", "Lat", "Lon"))
```

I have that in a dataframe called tabacouni.  R Studio tells me it is 254 observations of 8 variables.

Then I try

```
estado<-qmap("Alabama", zoom=7)
show(estado + geom_point(data=tabacouni, aes(x=Lon, y=Lat,size=Sample_Size),color="red") + theme(legend.position="none"))
```

And I get two things:

- A map of Alabama with no points overlaid
- A warning in the console that says "Removed 254 rows containing missing values (geom_point)."

I'm obviously missing something, but I can't see what...

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem; I get Alabama with a point at its center and no warnings. (However, I'm also not sure why you're making the map since all the Longitudes and Latitudes of your data are the same, overlaid at the center of Alabama)

Comment: Usually I'd expect that error when the points aren't in the region in question (for example, if they were all in California).

Comment: That was it actually!  Somehow in the file for the shiny app the zoom was set to 10, not 7...and so the lat/lon was outside the visible range.  I realize it's just one big point in the center of the state...I'm just trying to teach myself how to use this stuff :)